# Java - Bug in Shop System

Tags: java, debugging, methods, inventory-management

so I have a little inventory/shop interaction which is I can't find a solution for.

The player is supposed to be able to buy and sell items with a predefined buy/sell value in my Item class constructor. With the help of a scanner I'm able to sell without any bugs. However if I buy any quantity, the entire quantity is bought somehow. The item quantity is set to 0 after I buy any quantity once.

```
    private void buyItem() {
    System.out.println("Which item would you like to buy?");
    showStock();

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String itemName = "" + sc.next();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
        if (store[i] != null && store[i].getName().equals(itemName)) {
            // Checks if the given item name is available in the store
            System.out.println("We have " + store[i].getQuantity() + " " + store[i].getName() + "s in our stock. " + store[i].getBuyPrice() + " each");
            System.out.println("How many would you like to buy?");
            int buyQuantity = sc.nextInt();
            // Checks if there is enough in the stock
            if (buyQuantity > store[i].getQuantity()) {
                System.out.println("Not enough " + store[i].getName() + " available in the stock.");
                break;
            } else {
                // Checks if Player can afford it
                if (Player.getInstance().getCoins() >= store[i].getBuyPrice()) {
                    // Update player inventory
                    Player.getInstance().removeCoins(buyQuantity * store[i].getBuyPrice());
                    Item item = store[i];
                    item.setQuantity(buyQuantity);
                    Player.getInstance().getInv().addItem(item);
                    
                    // Buy transaction
                    store[i].setQuantity(store[i].getQuantity() - buyQuantity);
                    System.out.println("You have purchased " + buyQuantity + "x " + itemName);
                    System.out.println("Coins: " + Player.getInstance().getCoins());
                    
                    // Checks if the entire amount has been bought
                    if (buyQuantity == store[i].getQuantity()) {
                        store[i] = null;
                        System.out.println("That's all " + itemName + " the store had");
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You don't have enough coins to buy " + buyQuantity + " " + itemName + "s");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my console output from an example:

```
Which item would you like to buy?
Slot 0: Weapon
Slot 1: Cake
Slot 2: Arrow
Arrow
We have 100 Arrows in our stock. 2 each
How many would you like to buy?
10
You have purchased 10x Arrow
Coins: 980
That's all Arrow the store had
```

I've been trying and thinking for quite some time, but I can't figure out my bug. Do you have any suggestions? I tried debugging and everything was "working" the values were correct. But when I entered the quantity I would like to buy, my int output didn't affect anything. Would highly appreciate any tip!

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
Item item = store[i];
```

does not create a copy, but references the same object as is stored in the array `store`. The following

```
item.setQuantity(buyQuantity);
```

sets the quantity of the item in the `store` to `buyQuantity` and the following

```
store[i].setQuantity(store[i].getQuantity() - buyQuantity);
```

effectively reduces the count of the item to `0` (both in the store and in the player inventory).

As for the fix, one could use `clone()` but [this is regarded as broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch.html).

I would suggest a semantically different approach. Each item does not represent a single item, but a bundle of items. Thus, a specific amount can be added or removed to/from the bundle. For this to be feasible, I would make the common superclass `Item` (which I assume exists) generic in `T extends Item<T>`, `abstract` and give it a `public abstract T take(int amount);` method:

```
public abstract class Item<T extends Item<T>> {
    ...
    public abstract T take(int amount);
    ...
}
```

Then, I would change all subclasses to extend this superclass, e.g.

```
public class Arrow extends Item<Arrow> {
    public Arrow take(int amount) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, I would rename the classes to reflect clearly that each `Item` is a bundle of items. E.g., `Item` can be renamed to `ItemBundle` and `Arrow` can be renamed to `ArrowBundle` or `Arrows`.

Comment: Oh that makes perfectly sense

Comment: So do I need a clone method in my Item class to fix this problem? Or what would be the best approach?

Comment: Well `clone()` is a possibility, but [is regarded as broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch.html). Give me a moment to think about that.

Comment: Thank you for your time and a solution! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly changing the quantity of the purchased item to the amount requested by the player here:

```
Item item = store[i];
item.setQuantity(buyQuantity);
```

If you want to add x amount of `Item` the the player's inventory you need to create a new instance of that `Item` on which you set the `buyQuantity` to whatever amount was purchased. That way you keep the integrity of the store's stock.